# Drop newsletter emails with Postfix

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server, spam

There is an option, i have seen in Fortimail, that makes you able to filter/drop all newsletter emails.
I don't understand how Fortimail detects these type of emails.
And I am keen to know whether someone has any solution for this on Postfix mail server.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that will be part of the Postfix system itself, although it is almost certain there are plugins that will help.

A commonly used plugin is spamassassin, which parses email and provides a score based on various criteria.  There is nothing to stop you adding a plugin to drop newsletter emails.    The effectiveness of spamassassin in this instance really depends on a lot of variables, including the number of users, the rules you make/use and what you consider a newsletter.   (It could be as simple as tagging anything with "unsubscribe" in the body of the email, but that may be to general or not general enough.  Spamassassin gives you A LOT of control, but is non-trivial to use).

One advantage fortinet appears to have is the ability to do heuristics across a wide population of email across many servers which you may not be able to do yourself.  In other words, you may be able to craft a 95% solution while fortinet may be able to get a 99.5% solution  (figures plucked out of thin air)